# how to break columns in a table using jdbc

Tags: java, html, jsp, jdbc, html-table

I am making a simple table  which stores product details from database using jdbc connection.

My table looks like this:

```
    <table>

     <td>

    <img border="3"  
        src="image path" height="200" width="200" />

        <p align="center"></p>    // these tag contains specific product details from db
        <p align="center"></p> 

      </td>   
      </table>
```

right now I'm getting each product details in particular column( i.e multiple column within single row), but my problem is that this row keeps on expanding , & I want this row(which consist of multiple columns) to automatically break let say after every 5 products.

In simple words i want to arrange my products details in 4 x n format   just like in flipkart , as shown below:

http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/android-phones~type/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=hp_nmenu_sub_electronics_0_Android%20phones

you can see first product sony experia then lg then after samsung galaxy product, new row starts then again 4 products , then new row. In this way i need to show my products which are coming from database using jdbc connection.

Can anyone suggest me what's the best possible approach to achieve this. & Is there any option to break columns after 4th one & then start new row?

I am displaying database contents in jsp as shown below, just for demo:

```
       <%   
        //1. Retrieve all products from database   

        //1a.  Load the Driver   
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");   
        //1b.  Get a connection to the database   
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "un", "pwd
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table");   
        //1d.  Execute and retrieve our result   
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();   

        //2. Base on the results returned, construct a table   
    %>   
    </p>   

    <table border="0">    
     <%     

     if(rs.next()) {        
     rs.beforeFirst();  // for making sure you dont miss the first record.      
      while(rs.next())      
          {                        // opening while loop brackets.      

     %>        



        <td>   
     <div style=""><img border="3"  
        src="<%=rs.getString("image") %>" height="200" width="200" /></div>   


        <p align="center"><%=rs.getString("title")%></p>
        <p align="center"><%=rs.getString("price")%></p> 

       </td>   


        <%        
            } //closing while loop bracket      
         }        
         else {        
             //if no record is found, simply display a no record message        
     %>        
         Nothing.        
         <%        
         }        
      %>     

       </table>
```

Comment: `<tr>` and `</tr>` may prove helpful here.

Comment: Use div instead of table for a liquid layout...the one that will flow to next row based on the width of the screen.

Comment: @AC1 i have used div instead of table for liquid layout but product then comes one below the other. what should i use next?

Comment: Did you try css properties: display:inline; position:relative; float:left  for divs?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<tr>` tags to organize the table in rows. (That's what it stands for - *t*able *r*ow.)

Keep track of how many products (N) you've read from the database. If N is a multiple of 4 (`n % 4 == 0`), close the `<tr>` and start a new one.

So the result looks like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE** based on updated question:

Here's my tweak based on your code. I really do not advocate doing SQL calls (or really any non-presentation-layer code) from within a JSP, but that's a matter for a different question.

```
<%   
    //1. Retrieve all products from database   

    //1a.  Load the Driver   
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");   
    //1b.  Get a connection to the database   
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "un", "pwd
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table");   
    //1d.  Execute and retrieve our result   
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();   

    //2. Base on the results returned, construct a table   
%>   
</p>   

<table border="0">
  <tr>
   <%     

   int i = 0;
   if(rs.next()) {
   rs.beforeFirst();  // for making sure you dont miss the first record.      
     while(rs.next())      
       {                        // opening while loop brackets.
   %>

    <td>   
      <div style=""><img border="3"  
          src="<%=rs.getString("image") %>" height="200" width="200" /></div>   


      <p align="center"><%=rs.getString("title")%></p>
      <p align="center"><%=rs.getString("price")%></p> 

    </td>

    <%
      i++;
      if ((i % 4) == 0) {
    %>
        </tr>
    <%
      }

      if (!rs.isLast()) {  // don't open a new row if this is the last result
    %>
        <tr>
    <%
      }  // closing isLast check
    %>

    <%        
        } //closing while loop bracket      
     }        
     else {        
         //if no record is found, simply display a no record message        
 %>        
     Nothing.        
     <%        
     }        
  %>     
    </tr>

   </table>
```

I don't really have the patience to correct the whitespacing here, and I haven't actually compiled this, but hopefully you get the gist.

Comment: hey but where is it appropriate to put while loop according to your above table structure in order to get 4 columns and n rows

Comment: The table structure I provided is your output. Each `<tr>` is a table row. Put 4 `<td>`s in each `<tr>` and you have 4 columns and N rows. You don't put the loop *in* the table; you make a loop in your code to generate the above structure. What is your current code to generate your current table? Update your question and I'll update my answer.

Comment: please have  a look on my updated question , in the end i've mentioned my code (just for demo). if possible let me know the possible solution.

Comment: See updated answer. You could, instead of using `i`, use `rs.getRow()` to count your rows, but the docs say that that method isn't required universally, so it's probably better to keep count yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the response from dcsohl, you can use a combination of `<div>` and `<span>` elements.   A `<div>` element is a block element, that is, each `<div>` will be rendered in new line.  `<span>` element is an inline element.

This should help you:

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
<div>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```